# How to create a recursive Object in memory in Oracle 11g R2 and store it in Database

Tags: oracle, object, recursion, oracle11g

I have this code snippet to store expressions in database, let's call it example1:

```
create or replace type expression as object 
(
  type varchar2(400),
  MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN number
)NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;

create or replace type mutiplication under expression
(
  leftexpr ref expression,
  rightexpr ref expression,
  STATIC FUNCTION createMultiplication (leftexpr ref expression, rightexpr ref expression) return ref expression,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER
);
```

However I don't really want to store all the subexpressions in the database to be able to build up the object, so I'm trying to use this code, let's call it example2:

```
create or replace type expression as object 
(
  type varchar2(400),
  MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN number
)NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;

create or replace type mutiplication under expression
(
  leftexpr expression,
  rightexpr expression,
  STATIC FUNCTION createMultiplication (leftexpr expression, rightexpr expression) return expression,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER
);
```

First I didn't even try example2 code since i assumed it would not work because when i tried to use a type like this:

```
create or replace type expression as object 
(
  type varchar2(400),
  leftexpr expression,
  rightexpr expression,
  MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN number
);
/
```

I got this error message:

Oracle Error: PLS-00318
Error Description:
Type "expression" is malformed because it is a non-REF mutually recursive type;

When I actually tried the code and created a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE expression_table OF expression;
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: ORA-30756 "cannot create column or table of type that contains a supertype attribute" 
Cause: 
The user tried to create a column or table of an object type that contains a supertype attribute. This is not supported because it leads to infinite recursion in our current storage model. Note that creating a column of a type implies that we create columns corresponding to all subtype attributes as well.
```

So what I'm doing right now is combining example1 and example2 to be able to create recursive object purely in memory then store it another time and to be able to retrieve it.
Is there something less tedious then this?
This is the code I use now:

```
DROP TABLE expression_table;
DROP TYPE BODY SIMPLEN_SAVE;
DROP TYPE BODY MULTIPLICATION_SAVE;
DROP TYPE SIMPLEN_SAVE;
DROP TYPE MULTIPLICATION_SAVE;
DROP TYPE EXPRESSION_SAVE;
DROP TYPE BODY SIMPLEN;
DROP TYPE SIMPLEN;
DROP TYPE BODY MULTIPLICATION;
DROP TYPE MULTIPLICATION;
DROP TYPE EXPRESSION;


create or replace type expression_save as object 
(
  type varchar2(400),
  MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN number
)NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/

create or replace type multiplication_save under expression_save
(
  leftexpr ref expression_save,
  rightexpr ref expression_save,
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(p_leftexpr ref expression_save, p_rightexpr ref expression_save) return ref expression_save
);
/
create or replace type SIMPLEN_SAVE under expression_save
(
  datan number,
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(p_datan in number) return ref expression_save
);
/

CREATE TABLE expression_table OF expression_save
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
/

create or replace
type body multiplication_save as
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(p_leftexpr ref expression_save, p_rightexpr ref expression_save) return ref expression_save is
    ret ref expression_save;
    inst expression_save;
    rid rowid;
  begin
    inst := MULTIPLICATION_SAVE('MULTIPLICATION',p_leftexpr,p_rightexpr);

    insert into expression_table values(inst) returning rowid into rid;
    select ref(s) into ret from expression_table s where rowid = rid;
    return ret;
  end;
end;
/

create or replace type body SIMPLEN_SAVE as
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(p_datan in number) return ref expression_save is
    ret ref expression_save;
    inst expression_save;
    rid rowid;
  begin
    inst := SIMPLEN_SAVE('SIMPLEN',p_datan);

    insert into expression_table values(inst) returning rowid into rid;
    select ref(s) into ret from expression_table s where rowid = rid;

    return ret;
  end;
end;
/

create or replace function LOADEXPRESSION(ref expression_save) return expression is
  expr_save expression_save;
  begin
    select deref(expression_save) into expr_save from dual;
    if(expr_save.type = 'MULTIPLICATION')then
      return MULTIPLICATION('MULTIPLICATION',expression.LOAD((expr_save AS multiplication_save).leftexpr),expression.LOAD((expr_save AS multiplication_save).rightexpr));
    end if;

    if(expr_save.type = 'SIMPLEN')then
      return MULTIPLICATION('SIMPLEN',(expr_save AS multiplication_save).data);
    end if;

  end;
/

create or replace type expression as object 
(
  type varchar2(400),
  MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN number,
  MEMBER FUNCTION SAVE return ref expression_save
)NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/

create or replace type mutiplication under expression
(
  leftexpr expression,
  rightexpr expression,
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(p_leftexpr expression, p_rightexpr expression) return expression,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION SAVE RETURN ref expression_save
);
/

create or replace type body mutiplication as
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(p_leftexpr expression, p_rightexpr expression) return expression is
  begin
    return mutiplication('MULTIPLICATION',p_leftexpr,p_rightexpr);
  end;
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER is
  begin
    return leftexpr.eval * rightexpr.eval;
  end;
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION SAVE RETURN ref expression_save is
  begin
    return multiplication_save.crt(leftexpr.save, rightexpr.save);
  end;
end;
/

create or replace type simplen under expression
(
  data number,
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(data number) return expression,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION SAVE RETURN ref expression_save
);
/

create or replace type body simplen as
  STATIC FUNCTION CRT(data number) return expression is
  begin
    return simplen('SIMPLEN',data);
  end;
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER is
  begin
    return data;
  end;
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION SAVE RETURN ref expression_save is
  begin
    return simplen_save.crt(data);
  end;
end;
/
```

Comment: What error do you get?  The second set of statements works fine for me now that you've fixed the inheritance issue.

Comment: Thank you Justin, I didn't even try it, I updated my question once again. It all started from the mutually recursive expression type declared at the bottom.

Comment: OK.  This is now a completely different question.  The parent/ child class works because `expression` does not have a member of type `expression`.  There is no recursion-- the child object has members of the parent class.  Without the parent class, you're trying to create an object that has members that reference the type you're trying to create.  As the error indicates, you can't do that.

Comment: Yes but there is still recursion as the error message indicates when i try to create an object table of expression:
SQL Error: ORA-30756 "cannot create column or table of type that contains a supertype attribute"
Cause:
The user tried to create a column or table of an object type that contains a supertype attribute. This is not supported because it leads to infinite recursion in our current storage model. Note that creating a column of a type implies that we create columns corresponding to all subtype attributes as well.

Comment: Now you're talking about a new error message that occurs when you run some code that isn't part of your question.  And I'm not sure which of the three object implementations that unknown piece of code is using so it's hard to say anything useful.

Comment: Since eventually I would like to store the object in the database, I use this code in a script that ends with:

CREATE TABLE expression_table OF expression;

So the first is a pl/sql compiler error, because it can't make sense of recursive type definition that is referencing itself, I understand that now. The second is sql error because the architecture can't store recursive types, I assume it's because it can't allocate the space for them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122929/discussion-between-attila-horvath-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between these two classes?  You're indicating that `multiplication` should override the `eval` method but you are not indicating that `multiplication` should inherit from another class so there is no `eval` method to override.

If you intend for `multiplication` to be a child of `expression`, then you'd need the `under` clause

```
create or replace type mutiplication2 
  under expression
(
  leftexpr expression,
  rightexpr expression,
  STATIC FUNCTION createMultiplication (leftexpr expression, rightexpr expression) return expression,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

If you intend for `multiplication` to be a first-level object without inheritance, then you wouldn't use the `overriding` clause in defining your member function

```
create or replace type mutiplication as object
(
  leftexpr expression,
  rightexpr expression,
  STATIC FUNCTION createMultiplication (leftexpr expression, rightexpr expression) return expression,
  MEMBER FUNCTION eval RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

Comment: Yep i wanted inheritance, I didn't provide the code sample correctly I edited my question.